# Vanishing vector field, positive at the origin and negative at infinity

Tags: general-topology, optimization, convex-optimization, vector-fields

Let $F:\mathbb{R}^n_+\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n, \ (x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)\mapsto(F_1(x_1,...,x_n),...,F_n(x_1,...,x_n))$ be a vector field defined over the first quadrant of $\mathbb{R}^n$. That is, $\mathbb{R}^n_+=\{(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)\ |\ x_i\geq 0\text{ for all i}\}$. We assume that

- $F_i(\boldsymbol{0})>0$, and
- $\lim_{x_i\to\infty} F_i(\boldsymbol{x})=-\infty$ for all $i=1,2,\dots,n.$

My intuition tells me that **such a vector field must vanish at least once inside $\mathbb{R}^n_+$**, but I have not been able to prove this. I tried using Brouwer's Theorem and Poincare Miranda Theorem, but always found difficulties at the moment of defining the domains.

I am interested in this problem because I want to maximize a concave function whose gradient has the properties of $F$, so to show the existence of an equilibrium point I need to guarantee the existence of a solution of the equation $F(\boldsymbol{x})=0$. I appreciate any help you can give me.

Comment: Consider $F:\mathbb{R}^2_+\to \mathbb{R}^2$ given by $F(x,y)=(1-x-y,2-x-y)$, which satisfies your assumptions and never vanishes.

Comment: Thanks, @ParthShimpi, you are absolutely right. Now I am wondering if such a vector field must vanish somewhere if we further assume that it is the gradient of a strictly concave function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I commented, I was required to show the existence of an equilibrium point of a concave function in order to show maximality, but something I missed is that such a function can reach its maximum at the boundary, without the need to have an equilibrium point, even if it is strictly concave.

Consider for example the function $G(\boldsymbol{x})= -||\boldsymbol{x}||^2/2$, defined on the domain $\mathbf{D}=\{\boldsymbol{x}\ | \ ||\boldsymbol{x}||\geq R>0\}$. $G$ is strictly concave because its Hessian matrix is $-\boldsymbol{1}$ ($\boldsymbol{1}$ is the identity matrix), which is negative definite, but it reaches its maximum at any point $\boldsymbol{x}$ with $||\boldsymbol{x}||=R$ (*i.e.,* the maximum is not unique), and these are not critical points of $G$.

In conclusion, a strictly concave function can have multiple maxima if one of them is in the boundary. On the other hand, the maximum is unique if it is inside the domain.

**Edit.** The example function was changed from a Gaussian to the current one thanks to the clarification of @MathWonk.